# Finding the smallest min in and placing them in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a method that takes a 2d array and find the min value in each row. After it find the min in the row, I want that to go into another array. I have the array made, but I keep getting nulls in the array. This is probably an easy fix, but I've been looking at this for so long, I need some help.

```
public static double[][] largeArray;
public static double[] minArray;
public static double min;
private static void min()
{
    for ( int row=0; row < largeArray.length; row++)
    {
                  min = largeArray[row][0];

         for(int col = 1; col > largeArray[row].length; col++) 
         {
             if ( largeArray[row][col] < min )
                 min = largeArray[row][col];
             for(int t=0; t<minArray.length; t++)
             {
                min = minArray[row];
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Thank you for looking at this!

Comment: Nulls can come from not initializing arrays. Do you initialize the arrays before running the method? If yes, can you post the code where you do as well please?

Comment: You set `min`, you forgot to store it in `minArray[row]`. Which you should do after your inner loop - also, your third loop seems to be pointless.

Comment: I don't think I did initialize it, could I do that inside this method?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you explain that a little more, I'm confused as to what you are saying

Comment: @j.doe, yes you can.

Comment: @D.Law. How would you do that?

Comment: @j.doe, `minArray = new double[x][y];` `x` and `y` are values you decide upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't storing the `min` value(s) in `minArray`. You can also use [`Math.min(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-) in your loop. Finally, you want `<` (not `>`) in your inner loop condition and you could use [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-double:A-) to display the `minArray` when you have finished *initializing* it. Something like,

```
private static void min() {
    minArray = new double[largeArray.length]; // <-- initialize the array
    for (int row = 0; row < largeArray.length; row++) {
        min = largeArray[row][0];
        for (int col = 1; col < largeArray[row].length; col++) {
            min = Math.min(min, largeArray[row][col]);
        }
        minArray[row] = min;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(minArray));
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a null pointer. Plus I am trying to do this method without the collection classes

Comment: **Where** do you get a null pointer, and where and how have you made `minArray`?

Comment: at          minArray[row] = min;      and create it here public static double[] minArray;

Comment: Thank You so much! This helps so much!

Answer (score 0):

largeArray and minArray are typed as double[][], but you have not created them, therefore, they are null.

Comment: How would I create them? I know this sounds like a silly question, I am some what new to this